# How to access DLL from Java in Unity?

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, dllimport

I am a newbie to Unity and Java.
I have a project to modify a Unity game application.
I want to add the haptic feedback for this application using my device. I have DLL library "tensLib.dll" of my device, which is generated from .c and .h with Visual Studio 10.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html) accessing the DLL requires

```
@DllImport (DLLName)
static private function FooPluginFunction () : float {};
```

For C#, it should be

```
[DllImport("tensLibs.dll", EntryPoint="tens_init")]
public static extern int tens_init ([MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string port);
```

However, as my DLL is build from VC++, this requires adjustment. I tried

```
@DllImport("tensLibs.dll")
public static function tens_init ():int {};
```

with no success.

Comment: How far did you look for an answer? What did you learn from http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/access-dll-c-open-in-java.290481/ ?

Comment: Hi abecee, I have tried the methods on it (like I post before) public static function tens_init ():int {}; , but there is some error " The best overload for the method 'SoldierController.tens_init()' is not compatible with the argument list '(String)'"

Comment: how does that question relate to Java?

Comment: I try to modify a game in java script in unity, but I have difficulty to add a .dll in it.

Comment: @Limavolt please take note that Java is something entirely different than Java**Script**. Also, in Unity you are actually using their own version of JavaScript, which is called **Unity**Script. I don't believe you can use `DllImport` in UnityScript.

Comment: thank you ruud for your information